# remote debugging an iOS device connected to another computer

Tags: ios, xcode, remote-debugging

can I develop an iOS app on a mac, and run and debug it on an iOS device connected to another computer? If so, how?

Comment: If you have remote desktop access, then yes. You'd simply setup development stack on both computers and transfer the code between them (I'd recommend git). Why would you need this though? It is really cumbersome.

Comment: i've asked apple and according to them - there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality

Answer (score 0):

On device I haven't tested yet. I think you need some kind of pipeline for your automatic build tests, like OS X Server or Jenkins you have to choose which one you go for. I can recommend you install OS X Server then install Xcode for your continues integration.

for more information how to build Xcode server and Continuous Integration here is a detailed link from apple 
[Xcode Server and Continuous Integration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/)